# How to change host url websocket configurations?

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket

I have a problem about websocket client url. I want to use remote websocket server for my client machines.

```
Machine1, Machine2 --->  Remote Websocket Server
```

I have a config for websocket like this.

```xml
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/stomp" allowed-origins="*">
    <websocket:handshake-handler ref="myHandshakeHandler"/>
        <websocket:sockjs client-library-url="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1/dist/sockjs.min.js"/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
            
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic,/queue"/>
    <websocket:client-inbound-channel>
        <websocket:interceptors>
            <ref bean="myInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:interceptors>
    </websocket:client-inbound-channel>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

I want to post and get remote url for websocket operations so I can multiple my gui machines. How to change to websocket host url `localhost` to `https://remotemachineurl:61614`.

Comment: Thank you Justin you help me a lot.When deleting the artemis tag. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this config on my xml, and I can connect remote activemq artemis.

```xml
<websocket:stomp-broker-relay prefix="/topic,/queue" relay-host="remotehost" relay-port="61614"/>
```